# Which model to use to classify a text to a topic, among a list of topics?

Tags: text-classification, gpt

I want to find to which topics a text belongs.

A topic is a question (~ 15 words)
nb_topics = 250
nb_texts ~ 15000

The texts and topics are in French

How can I do this with BERT or GPT-3? Any guideline?

Comment: You can use any of the popular sentence embedding models like Doc2Vec and create embeddings for each the questions. After doing so, you'll have a fixed dimensional embedding for each question along with its label. You can now use any of the NN architectures to solve this classification problem.

Comment: But I thought that embeddings had only meaning for words

Comment: Refer to [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-doc2vec-logistic-regression-9da9947b43f4) tutorial that uses Doc2Vec to perform text classification.

Comment: And what would be the predictive variables ? Since each text don't have the same number of words, what will the variables be ?

Comment: explore the tutorial that I have mentioned in the above comment. It matches your usecase.